# how to solve Circular dependency between resources: [s3bucketvideo, S3InvokeLambdaPermission]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Thanks in advance.
I am trying to create s3 bucket and lambda function. Goal is to execute lambda function as we upload anything on an s3 bucket. I have tried different methods but doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
Resources:
s3bucketvideo:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DependsOn: S3InvokeLambdaPermission
    Properties:
        BucketName: s3bucketvideo
        NotificationConfiguration:
            LambdaConfigurations:
              - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
                Function: !GetAtt VideoToImageLambda.Arn
        
S3InvokeLambdaPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        FunctionName: !Ref VideoToImageLambda
        Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
        SourceArn: !GetAtt s3bucketvideo.Arn
    
cflambdarole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties: 
        RoleName: cflambdarole
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Principal:
                  Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
                Action: sts:AssumeRole
        ManagedPolicyArns:
            - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess
            - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaExecute
            - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

VideoToImageLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
        FunctionName: VideoToImageLambda
        Timeout: 120
        Role:
            Fn::GetAtt:
                - cflambdarole
                - Arn
        Runtime: python3.9
        Handler: script.hprint
        Code:
            S3Bucket: s3-neuralopsdev
            S3Key: script.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution is to use SourceAccount instead of SourceArn in the permission:

```
SourceAccount: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
```

After you create the stack, you can also add SourceArn and do an update.

This is also discussed [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/resolving-circular-dependency-in-provisioning-of-amazon-s3-buckets-with-aws-lambda-event-notifications/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.
I used **SourceAccount** and it created the stack but without notification trigger.
Is it possible to do it in **create_stack** only?

I checked the source which you pasted. It is something related to custom notification.

Comment: I believe that you need a custom resource to do it in create_stack only. I also think that the notification should be created with SourceAccount only - it would be too open though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Notication is not being created with SourceAccount. It says I would need to write a new lambda function for my custom resource. I am not aware about how to create function for custom resource.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update.
I created the stack without bucket notification and then updated the stack with bucket notification for a quick solution.
It did the trick.